# Why does Java main method code execute, despite calling a Thread's run( ) method?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class RunnableThreadExample implements Runnable {

    public int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnableThreadExample instance = new RunnableThreadExample();
        Thread thr = new Thread(instance);
        thr.start();        
        while(instance.count != 5) {            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println(" Within main method");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(count < 5) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Sleeping for 500 seconds within run method");
                Thread.sleep(500);              
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            count++;
        }       
    }   
}
```

I notice the Sys out within main method simultaneously run while the Sys out within run ( ) method is executed.

```
The output looks as follows:
Sleeping for 500 seconds within run method
Sleeping for 500 seconds within run method
 Within main method
Sleeping for 500 seconds within run method
 Within main method
 Within main method
Sleeping for 500 seconds within run method
Sleeping for 500 seconds within run method
 Within main method
 Within main method
 Within main method
```

When we call thr.start( ), shouldn't the execution be completed at run( ) and then come back to the line while(instance.count != 5) { ??

Comment: The whole point of starting a new `Thread` is that it then executes independently of the thread that started it.

Comment: each runs on it's own thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `run` method will *not* be called from the main thread. Instead, `start` creates a new thread of execution (independent from the main thread), and that new thread executes `run`. The main thread will immediately (without waiting what happens to the new thread) resume the next instruction after `start`.

This kind of concurrency is exactly why you want to use `Thread`.